# caption on top of table not coming with this code

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[H]
\label{table:a}
\centering
\caption{N-type material groups by best temperature range}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Group                            & Material                                                    & Best Temperature Range(K)                                                      &  &  \\ \midrule
Hot Side Material (700 K-1000 K) & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}CoSb3\\ PbTe\\ SiGe\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}650-110\\ 600-850\\ \textgreater{}1000\end{tabular} &  &  \\
Cold Side Material (300 K-400 K) & Bi2Te3                                                      & \textless{}350                                                                 &  &  \\
                                 &                                                             &                                                                                &  &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can mark your code as such by selecting it and pressing the "{}" button in the editor (like I just did for you). Additionally it would be good if you posted an MWE that is actually a complete minimal document that we can compile and not just a fragment. This means it should include everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` to compile your example with as few packages as possible.

Comment: Also please note that in order to get the cross-references right, you have to put `\label` either directly after `\caption{...}` or (even better) inside the argument of `\caption` like this: `\caption{<your caption>\label{tab:a}}` (make sure to not put spaces before or after the label in that case).

Comment: Apart from the issue Skillmon mentioned, your code works as expected if one uses the `article` documentclass and the `booktabs` package. The reason must therefor be hidden in the code that you did not show. Therefore please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Embedding your fragment into a simple example document `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{float,booktabs}\begin{document}<your code>\end{document}` does set the caption above the tabular. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the output you get? Can you please edit the code in your question to actually produce your wrong output, and include a description of what you try to get?

Answer (score 2):

- with information which you provide is not possible to reproduce your problem

[image]

- some off-topic comments (besides given in the comments below your question):

  - don't use `H`. it destroy floating mechanism and consequently can lead to unexpected ugly result. better is to use for example `!ht`
  - why you define five columns and than you use only three?
  - for chemical formulas is fine to use macros from the `mhchem` package
  - for values with units is good to use `siunitx` package
  - for multi line cells' contents is handy to use the `\makecell` command from `makecell` package

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{N-type material groups by best temperature range}
    \label{table:a}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll l}
        \toprule
    Group   & Material  & Best Temperature Range        \\
        \midrule
    Hot Side Material (\SIrange{700}{1000}{\kelvin})
        & \makecell[tl]{\ce{CoSb3}\\ \ce{PbTe}\\ \ce{SiGe} }
            & \makecell[tl]{\SIrange{650}{1100}{\kelvin}\\
                            \SIrange{600}{850}{\kelvin}\\
                            \SI{>1000}{\kelvin} }       \\
        \addlinespace
    Cold Side Material (\SIrange{300}{400}{\kelvin})
        & \ce{Bi2Te3}
            & \SI{<350}{\kelvin}                        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
    ```

for further help, please (as you was already asked), provide complete small document with your table. it seems that information in document preamble are source of your problem.

**addendum**:
according to @Skillmon comments, is better to say that numbers in the last columns are temperatures in Kelvin's degree and than write just numbers only:

```
...
\begin{tabular}{ll c}
    \toprule
Group   & Material  & Best Temperature Range (K)      \\ % <---
    \midrule
Hot Side Material (\SIrange{700}{1000}{\kelvin})
    & \makecell[tl]{\ce{CoSb3}\\ \ce{PbTe}\\ \ce{SiGe} }
        & \makecell[t]{\SIrange{650}{1100}{}\\  % <--- no units in "SI"
                        \SIrange{600}{850}{}\\  % <--- no units in "SI"
                        \SI{>1000}{} }       
                                                    \\
    \addlinespace
Cold Side Material (\SIrange{300}{400}{\kelvin})
    & \ce{Bi2Te3}
        & \SI{<350}{}                            % <--- no units in "SI"             
                                                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
...
```

which gives

[image]

in case of big tables this is reasonable and better solution.

Comment: The usage of `siunitx` is wrong in the third column, the table header already contains the unit, so the cells in that column shouldn't.

Comment: @Skillmon, you are right. this column has other inconsistency too (two ranges are from low temperature to high, one is opposite (or there is typing error and should be `\SIrange{650}{1100}{\kelvin}\\` . who knows. to me the table will be more clear, if i delete  `K` from column header. i will correct answer on this ways asap.

Comment: While this might be clearer to you, it is by convention done the other way around, namely if every cell of a column uses the same unit, the unit should be only in the header.

Comment: @Skillmon, i consider your comments :-)

Comment: (Sorry, it might seem that I'm never satisfied) You should use `\numrange` and `\num` instead of `\SIrange` and `\SI` in the last column (they are also added by `siunitx`).